# Mvc4 website locally working fine but gives error on IIS Server 8.5 after deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, jqgrid

hello i developed my website in mvc4 and i am using JQGrid in my application. my website is working fine on my local system but when i deploy website on my local IIS Server 8.5 then it gives error in loading the jq grid controller method am using windows 8.1 Console error image is attached below.

[image]

guide me about this error. is there any changes made in web.config or at IIS Server. thank you

and below screen shot of deployment how i deploy my website into local IIS.
[image]

Comment: Is the Static File handler enabled in IIS? Are your MVC routes too greedy and handling requests for non-Actions? Do the files actually exist on the server (because ASP.NET Web Deployment might miss files)?

Comment: how to disable Static File handler in IIS? and also guide me the method of deployment i am using web deploy method for publish website on my localhost. let me add one more screenshot of my deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your Web Publish configuration isn't uploading/publishing those files. Ensure that those files are included in your `.csproj` project (Solution Explorer > Show All Files > Include, for each file listed). Also ensure that "All files" rather than "Files needed to run the application" is selected on the Settings page of the Web Publish wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you don't included `Content/images` subdirectory and `fonts` subdirectory (or some files from there) *to your project*. So the destination don't contains the required files.